# Can iMac use CLLocationManager?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4

Or is it just for IPhone?

By extension, can IPhone simulator use CLLocationManager

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Mac OS X Snow Leopard, an iMac (or any other Mac) has the CoreLocation framework, including `CLLocationManager`.

The iPhone simulator uses directly CoreLocation on the Mac since the iOS 4 SDK if I'm correct (before that using CoreLocation on the simulator would always point to the Apple headquarters).

Comment: I did and it always return null

Comment: On the simulator or in a Mac app?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Core Location on the desktop - but without a GPS it estimates your position using the wifi networks around you. It's surprisingly accurate (in London, at least).

I think this was how the original, pre GPS, iPhones used to estimate your current location.